# How to get loaded link

Tags: php, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm creating a script on my localhost xammp, this script is fetching download links from this website [Primewire.ag](https://www.primewire.ag/watch-2757658-Camp-Massacre-online-free)

I have successfully created the script and get href links but i am stuck here, when I use inspect element in browser on Version 2, Version 3 or the download links table you can see that the link that is shown in the href attribute is like this:

`/external.php?title=Camp+Massacre&amp;url=aHR0cDovL3ZpZHppLnR2L2Z3eWM4bmZreDJ3eC5odG1s&amp;domain=dmlkemkudHY=&amp;loggedin=0`

And when you click on this link it will open on new window and now the real  link loaded is `http://vidzi.tv/fwyc8nfkx2wx.html`.

I want to get the real link, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Just do base64 decode of  url value you will get "http://vidzi.tv/fwyc8nfkx2wx.html"

Comment: thank you bro you are genius. i get it bro now please can you help me please this link `/external.php?title=Camp+Massacre&amp;url=aHR0cDovL3ZpZHppLnR2L2Z3eWM4bmZreDJ3eC5odG1s&amp;domain=dmlkemkudHY=&amp;loggedin=0` i only want this `vidzi.tv/fwyc8nfkx2wx.html` from above link how i can code this

Comment: Akhil Thayyil sir please post your answer i want to make your answer correct so you can earn points and sir please if you can also help me in answer for only url part get from long url for decode this will very help full for me

Comment: Try some code of your own, if you cannot get it to work ask for more help. [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

I combined all the comments into my own answer and would like to share it with you guys. See beneath.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file("https://www.primewire.ag/watch-2757658-Camp-Massacre-online-free");
$link = array();
foreach($html->find('div.choose_tabs div.actual_tab table.movie_version ') as $download){
    $link[] = $download->find('tr td span.movie_version_link a',0)->href;
}

foreach($link as $lin){
    $parts = parse_url($lin);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    echo base64_decode($query['url']) . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vidzi is pretty easy to scrap. You can get the hotlink fetching the download page with a little DOM manipulation.

When you fetch a vidzi link you've to find the IP and port where the video is hosted, for that you can use the preview image that's hosted in the same server.

```
.video-preview-left > img
```

Explode the image **src** to the the IP and port. Then you need to get the video ID, as the original URL contains the page ID.

ID is passed in javascript. It's the string between:

```
thumbnails|kind|vtt|tracks|mp4|
```

and

```
|hls|type|embed|m3u8
```

mp4|**ID-string**|hls

And voilá, you have the ID. The hotlink will be:

```
ip:port/video-ID/v.mp4
```